# Keyboard shows up automatically when the app starts?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, keyboard

In my MainActivity, I've added an EditText.
When the user opens the app, the keyboard automatically shows up to let the user type text, but my app shows ads in onCreate(), therefore I want to disable that automatic event, is that possible?

Comment: It sounds like you're automatically focusing the text input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the AndroidManifest.xml you can use the following settings:

```
<activity android:name="com.your.package.ActivityName" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

You can also try:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

You can find more details at this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible, you have two options to achieve this.

**Option 1:** 
Adding below code in your layout - xml file

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

**Option 2:**

Adding below code in your manifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

simply add this line to your android manifest file to disable the showing keyboard. (activity of yours)

Answer (score 0):

Use these  functions to show/hide the keyboard:

**Hides the soft keyboard**

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    if(getCurrentFocus()!=null) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

**Shows the soft keyboard**

```
public void showSoftKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    view.requestFocus();
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, 0);
}
```

Or you can set windowSoftInputMode : stateHidden

```
    <activity
    ... 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
```